# MQTT: shared connection for consumers and publishers?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am migrating an application from RabbitMQ to MQTT.  From what I understand, Rabbit suggests opening separate broker connections for consumer / publisher.  Does MQTT have any defined best practices in this regard?  Or is it considered best practice to share a single connection for consumers and publishers?

Answer (score 2):

In most MQTT implementations, you can use the MQTT Broker connection for both Publishing and Subscribing.  I don't know if it is considered a "Best Practice" or not, but I usually just connect once and do both in my solutions.